# Throwing exception when designated amount of memory is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, out-of-memory

I was creating unit test for one of my methods where it creates a byte array with specified amount of elements. Like so:

```
public byte[] GenerateElements(int amount){

Stack<int> st=new Stack<int>();
Random rnd=new Random();
for(int i=0;i<amount;i++){
st.Push(rnd.Next(0,100));
}
//After that stack to array conversion etc...

}
```

And in my unit test:

```
[Fact]
....
{
//....
Random rnd = new Random();
int amount=rnd.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
GenerateElements(amount);
//...Asserts

}
```

But as you can guess, it might happen to send really big value like int.MaxValue to the method whereas method will create that much amount of elements for array and stack.

How should i handle it ? Curretly, in case it gets big value from random, it just locks the pc into unrecoverable state. Doesn't throw MemoryLeak or OutOfMemory exception. Any help or idea is appreciated, thank you.

PS: I have to assert/test high value parameters for that method.

Comment: Does your program have an expected upper-bound that you can use that isn't `MaxValue`?  Also, the reason you're not getting an OutOfMemoryException is that because you're allocating many many many small integers, it's going to start paging to disk before it actually dies a horrible death.

Comment: It currently doesn't have an upper limit. But i would like to make upper-bound limit dynamic according to the users hardware specs (if possible). And throw exception when that limit is reached.

Comment: so what is it?  What is it about the user's hardware... What are you trying to achieve here by finding out when adding too many integers to a stack puts you in a dark room?